# Перекрывание свойства в фейковом объекте

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, наследование, mock, moq

Есть продакшен код вот такого вида:

```
public class User : UserBase
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    //...
}

public class UserBase
{
    public AddressType AddressType { get; }

    //...
}

public class AddressType : AddressTypeBase
{
    //...
}

public abstract class AddressTypeBase
{
    public string Code { get; }

    //...
}
```

Пытаюсь написать юнит-тест для метода, который принимает объект `User` в качестве параметра. В данном методе идет обращение к свойству `User.AddressType.Code`, а его инициализация в тестовом окружении очень сложна. Я пытался с помощью Moq как-то замокать это дело, но ничего не вышло.

Теперь решил посредством создания фейкового объекта:

```
public class FakeUser : User
{
    public new AddressType AddressType => new FakeAddressType("TestCode");

    public class FakeAddressType : AddressType
    {
        public new string Code { get; }

        public FakeAddressType(string code)
        {
            Code = code;
        }
    }
}
```

И вроде как все получилось, но результат вызова:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fakeUser = new FakeUser();
        var addressTypeCode = fakeUser.AddressType.Code;
    }
}
```

таков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Происходит некая магия c наследованием и я пытаюсь разобраться что к чему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думал, что если базовый вариант свойства перекрывается посредством `new AddressType AddressType`, то ссылка FakeUser сможет обращаться только к своей копии этого свойства. Но на скриншоте выше можно увидеть, что она хранит оба варианта или быть может VS и ReSharper мне неверно что-то подсказывают. В любом случае, при обращении к `fakeUser.AddressType.Code` был вызван базовый вариант.

Что я неправильно делаю и можно ли вообще как-то замокать это свойство тем подходом, что я пытаюсь применить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так с кастом будет работать, подходит ли вам такой вариант?

```csharp
var addressTypeCode = ((FakeAddressType)fakeUser.AddressType).Code;
```

Ну либо вот такой вариант вместо предыдущего

```csharp
public new FakeAddressType AddressType => new FakeAddressType("TestCode");
```

Просто по умолчанию берется то значение свойства, которое соответствует его типу, чтобы взять переопределенное, нужно либо тип переопределенного значения использовать, либо каст в этот тип, собственно это и показано выше.